# Automation of localized language web app

Tags: java, selenium, pom.xml

I do not have any question but I need suggestions for my approach . 
I am testing a web app which can be converted to a local language from English language and vice versa by selecting language from dropdown. I am using Selenium with Java to automate it. Because this is a first time I am doing this kind of automation so I search a lot on google. From google I found mostly ppl used an approach where they have generated a properties files and stored the local language characters into ASCII values. I need suggestion from all the senior members. The scenario which I am trying to achieve is I want to use the same script to run on English language as well as in local language without making any code change. Right now I am doing is reading english ascii values and comparing with english ascii values and if I have to execute it in chinese I read chinese ascii values and compare with expected chinese ascii values. 
Here is my approach.
For UI validation:1. First I have generated a properties files which stores the converted local language characters to ASCII value (expectedValue). Secondly,  manually I have generated another expectedValue properties files and using google translator and other online app manually found the ASCII values. Lastly I ma reading expected and actual properties files using java and using selenium assert condition I am comparing the expectedValue and  actualValue to check if they are same. The only disadvantage (may be) is the expected and actual ascii properties file is growing pretty big but I did not find any solution to control the size. 
For functional Testing (the dropdown values are in local language) here is my approach.
1. Suppose I have to create a certain type of user (certain type eg admin but admin text is in local language in dropdown). I am reading the input data from my json file and start sending to webform (in usual way sendKeys) and the place where I have to select the dropdown entry I am reading the local language admin ascii value from properties files and finding the web element by Pass by reference and selecting the data in local language from dropdown. Because this is the start of automation (localization) so I want to make all the improvements/changes in the initial stage of automation not in later stage where the cost to make a small change is very high. Please give you suggestions for my approach.

Comment: SO is not a blogging service. Please have read through [ask].

Comment: @SiKing, yes I know this is not a blogging service . All I need is suggestion for my approach where I can improve. If you want me to share the code yes I can but I do not have any question on code side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first project I ever worked on as an automator involved this kind of scenario.  What we did was to store the expected (tested) text values in separate XML files, one for each language, but all using the same key values for lookup.  Then each story (we use JBehave BDD) would pass the site code as a parameter, which would determine the language, except int he case of Canada where it could be either English or French, so one file was stored for each language for that particular site.  Eventually for simplicity we merged all the XML files into one large one and just used the site/language parameter as another lookup key, but the effect was the same.

I hope this helps answer your question.